# How does Generator.next() processes its parameter?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

The [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator/next) says that "You can also provide a parameter to the next method to send a value to the generator." Where does it sends it to?

For example, take these 3 generators:

```
function* one() {
  while(true) {
    var value = yield null;
  }
}
var g1 = one();  g1.next();
g1.next(1000); //yields null

function* two() {
  var i = 0;
  while (true) {
    i += yield i;
  }
}
var g2 = two(); g2.next(); 
g2.next(1000) // yields 1000

function* three(){
  var index = 0;
  while (true)
    yield index++;
}

 g3 = three();
 g3.next();
 g3.next(1000); // yields 1
```

In generators 3 and 1, the argument passed has no effect on `next`. Why is that? How does generator 2 calculates its return value? Why it is affected by the given argument?

Comment: the passed in value appears to be returned from the yield. https://jsfiddle.net/ret4zbsk/ `0 += 1000 = 1000`

Comment: @KevinB Mmm, I still don't understand why doesn't the third generator returns 1001...

Comment: misread. basically, index++ iterates after, not before. try ++index

Comment: dunno, i still get 1,2,3 from that. however, if i add index = yield index++, i do get differing results. The key seems to be that you update the variable with the yield.

Comment: dunno. it doesn't make logical sense, even the mdn example. I would have expected that to log 1, not 2. The yield is reached first, and yields null. Then on next call, it should log the value of `value`, which should still be 1, then it iterates and yields null again. but no, it logs 2. where did `1` go? does it ignore the first passed in value all together? Sure seems to. https://jsfiddle.net/zuasLu9s/

Comment: @KevinB I posted an 'interpretation' of the documentation as an answer. Does it makes sense to you?

Comment: All except for... where does the first value you pass in go? https://jsfiddle.net/zuasLu9s/1/

Comment: I'm assuming that since it hasn't yielded yet, it doesn't have a point to return that value to, and it's returning the value you pass in to .next() from the previous occurence of `yield`. so the first value just gets ignored.

Comment: Documentation says "Note that the first call did not log anything, because the generator was not yielding anything initially." I don't think I have grasped it yet, though.

Comment: I read that, i was trying to understand the `why` that is the case.

Comment: Ah, i get it. basically, what you're passing in is being returned from the previous yield, so that the next processing up until the next yield can use it to modify the result. For example, https://jsfiddle.net/zuasLu9s/3/ Since there was no previous yield before the first call to .next(), there's nothing to return to so it just ignores that first value. If you don't accept what is being returned (such as your `three` generator above) the passed in value won't have any effect. Here's a simpler example: https://jsfiddle.net/7zgyv1a6/1/

Comment: Set a breakpoint on your generator `one` and inspect the value of `value`. That should answer all of your questions.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The key to understanding this is knowing how the next function retrieves the argument passed to `next()`, which is as the return value of the yield operator:

```
[rv] = yield [expression];
```

Independently of the value of [expression], yield will assign to `rv` the value passed to `next()`.

But, here comes the tricky part: yield will only assign the value passed to next() when resuming execution from a previous iteration. As a consequence, on the first iteration, `yield` does not assign anything to rv.

For example, if I have this generator:

```
function* gen() {
  // On the first iteration, yield does not return anything.
  //because it returns something ONLY when execution is resumed
  returnedFromYield = yield 'foo'; 
  yield returnedFromYield; 
}
```

`returnedFromYield` is undefined on the first iteration. When execution is resumed on the second iteration, yield assigns the passed value to the `returnedFromYield` variable, which is then returned:

```
g.next(1); // 'foo'
g.next(2); // 2
```

Let's review another example:

```
function* gen() {
  yield yield yield 5;
}
```

On the first iteration, (`g.next()`), yield will return 5, on the second iteration, (`g.next(10)`) yield is going to pass 10 to the second yield. That is, `yield yield yield 5;` on the second iteration is equivalent to `yield yield 10;`, and, on the third iteration, it's equivalent to `yield valuePassedToNext`.

Answer (score 5):

Here's an annotated example showing the logical flow and scope for the values passed to a generator's next method. The affected area of the `next` method call is highlighted in the corresponding color.

[image]

**a:** There is no yield, so argument 'one' is ignored. The generator pauses on line 5, returning the value 1.

**b:** Execution resumes and 'two' replaces yield on line 5, and is assigned to the `yieldValue` variable. Line 6 is executed. The generator pauses on line 8, returning the value 2.

**c:** Execution resumes and 'three' replaces yield on line 8, and is assigned to the `yieldValue` variable. Line 9 is executed. The generator pauses on line 11, returning the value 3.

**d:** Execution resumes and 'four' replaces yield on line 11, and is assigned to the `yieldValue` variable. Line 12 is executed. Line 14 is executed. Finally the generator is now done, returning the value `undefined`.

*See the logs on line 28-36*

Comment: Thank you @Christopher. I was so much confused, Your example helped a lot :D

Comment: You're so welcome @sachinyadav :) I'm glad I could help!