# How Generator works?

Tags: javascript

I am reading [JavaScript Generators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*) and I have a doubt regarding the below program.

How first `it.next()` giving `"Hello"` as an output? It would be great if anyone explains it in detail step by step.

```js
function* foo(x) {
  var y = x * (yield "Hello"); // <-- yield a value!
  return y;
}

var it = foo(6);

var res = it.next(); // first `next()`, don't pass anything
console.log(res.value); // "Hello"

res = it.next(7); // pass `7` to waiting `yield`
console.log(res.value); // 42
```

Comment: Also read more on `next` receiving params [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37354461/how-does-generator-next-processes-its-parameter).

Answer (score 0):

I will explain it step by step:

**Step1**: you have created a generator function called `foo`

**Step2**: you have assign the generator function to a variable called it and passing value 6 (assigning value x=6).

**Step3**: you are calling `next` function on the generator object. Magic happens here. It will start executing function until it will not find the first `yield`. Once it reaches to the first `yield`, it will stop execution and return value.