# In what order is this generator running code at each call of next()?

Tags: javascript, iterator, generator

```js
function* bankAccount() {
  let balance = 0;
  while (balance >= 0) {
    balance += yield balance;
  }
  return 'bankrupt! ';
}

let userAccount = bankAccount();

console.log(userAccount.next());
console.log(userAccount.next(10));
console.log(userAccount.next(-15));
```

...this code works - I've run it and after the third call of next(), it returns bankrupt - but why? Surely when next() is called the third time, the loop will check the balance (which will still be 10 at that point), and then add -15 to the balance, and yield out -5...leaving the next iteration to yield bankrupt.

But thats obviously not the case, the balance seems to be updated with the yield value before the loop checks the current balance, but if that line of code is running first, then why is the loop running at all? wouldn't it just be yielding out the updated balance instantly?...so, which code is being run when?

Comment: "*and then add -15 to the balance, and yield out -5.*" no. It's not even related to generators. It's as simple as `balance` is `10`, you add `-15`, it becomes `-5`, loops and it fails `balance >= 0`, so it doesn't execute the body of the `while` again. Try it with just `balance = 10; while(balance >= 0) { balance -= 5 }` and you'll never get to `-5`: https://jsbin.com/zomamup/edit?js,console

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does Generator.next() processes its parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37354461/how-does-generator-next-processes-its-parameter)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Order of operations:

1. `let balance = 0;`
2. `while (balance >= 0) {` - balance is 0 here
3. `yield balance` - yields 0
4. `balance += <value passed to next = 10>` - balance is 10 after that
5. `while (balance >= 0) {` - balance is 10
6. `yield balance` - yields 10
7. `balance += <value passed to next = -5>` - balance is -5 after that
8. `while (balance >= 0) {` - balance is -5 so break
9. `return 'bankrupt! ';`

```js
function* bankAccount() {
  let balance = 0;
  while (balance >= 0) {
    balance += yield balance;
    console.log('inside loop', balance)
  }
  console.log('after loop', balance)
  return 'bankrupt! ';
}

let userAccount = bankAccount();

userAccount.next();
userAccount.next(10);
userAccount.next(-15);
```

Comment: That much is obvious, but how to the `.next()` calls relate to this order of operations?

Comment: I guess that OP thought that `balance += yield balance` is called with an old value and the new value would be used the next time `yield balance` is called. As if `balance +=` would run first and `yield balance` second. That's what I thought before debugging at least :)

Answer (score 2):

> Surely when next() is called the third time, the loop will check the balance (which will still be 10 at that point), and then add -15 to the balance, and yield out -5.

This is nearly all correct. The biggest problem with it is that (as @Bergi correctly points out in the comments), the adding of -15 happens *before* the check. Therefore the conclusion:

> and yield out -5

is wrong.

When -15 is added to the balance, which happens on this line when you called `next` with the -15 argument:

```
balance += yield balance;
```

`balance` becomes -5, as you so rightly observe. So the next statement execute is the loop check itself. `balance >= 0` is no longer true, so it doesn't loop again, and moves on to the final `"bankrupt"` yield - exactly as you've observed.

Perhaps your confusion is over how the `next` calls and `yield`s line up. So here's a quick summary:

- the first `.next()` call advanced the code to the first `balance += yield balance;`, where `balance` is 0. That's what's yielded, and the code awaits your next call to see what's added to `balance`.
- then you call `.next(10)`, so `10` gets added to `balance`. It reaches that line again, so `10` is yielded, and again the generator waits to see what you give it next.
- then you call `.next(-15)`, which yields the `10` value. As observed above, the next `yield` is outside the loop because balance is now -5 and the loop therefore does not continue

Comment: "*This is nearly all correct*" - no, it's mixing up the order of operations. When `.next()` is called for the third time, it doesn't start with "the loop will check the balance". It starts with adding the `-15` to the balance, only the the loop check will occur.

Comment: @Bergi thanks, you're right, I'd overlooked the order stated here (but got it right in my detailed summary later). I'll add a quick note to that effect.

Answer (score 0):

It is about how yield works, you can read in depth [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/yield).

In your example the `yield` keyword causes the function generator to **stop before the balance is increased**, the following `.next()` call will increase the value, so in reality the loop goes as follows:

**1st call** -> balance is 0 as defined, we enter the while loop, but stop before the balance increase by yielding the current `balance` value

**2nd call** -> the `yield` expression results in `10`, the balance is increased to 10, only now the first iteration is complete, we enter the loop again, but stop before balance increase by yielding the current `balance` value

**3rd call** -> the `yield` expression results in `-15`, the balance becomes -5, the while condition is not valid anymore